# Ubuntu USB to serial device connection problem

Tags: 16.04, usb, serial-port

I have bumped into some problems regarding USB connection, I’ve tried the following commands but I still can’t get a connection working:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0955:09ff NVidia Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 1a86:5523 QinHeng Electronics CH341 in serial mode, usb to serial port converter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I’m sure that the device I’m connecting to is:

```
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 1a86:5523 QinHeng Electronics CH341 in serial mode, USB to serial port converter
```

I have also tried the following:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1a86 produbt=0x5523
dmesg
```

Which apparently should return:

```
usbserial_generic 1-1:1.0: generic converter detected
usb 1-1: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
```

Based on the examples I’ve seen, showing connection to `ttyUSB0`, but in my case I got:

```
[ 4534.021812] usb 1-3.1: new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci-tegra
[ 4534.047806] usb 1-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=5523
[ 4534.054825] usb 1-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Does this mean that I have made a successful connection?

The hardware I’m using is “nvidia jetson tx1” on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am able to connect to `ttyUSB0` from my laptop to the device. Can some one help me with this issues?

Comment: Try the following: disconnect USB adapter, open terminal and enter `journalctl -f` in it, connect USB adapter. Then copy console output and paste it to the question. Also add output of `ls -al /dev/ttyUSB? /dev/ttyACM?` to the question.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is having this issue with Ubuntu 22.10 and connecting a 3d Printer to Serial over USB - brltty takes over and assumes full control of ttyUSB0 - so have to either uninstall or (somehow) disable brltty.

I uninstalled brltty:

```
sudo apt remove brltty
```

then rebooted, and set:

```
[mcu]
serial: /dev/ttyUSB0
```

in `printer.cfg` of Klipper

worked fine after reboot.

Comment: Thanks that indeed solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with a CH340 chip on Ubuntu 22.04. Following Daniel's advise, I removed brltty, rebooted, and my cheap Arduinos with CH340 work again.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed brltty to, and it worked, this time with a WEMOS D1 R1 Arduino clone, which has no CH340 system.